# Write Xcode console log into a file in mac

Tags: ios, xcode, logging

i already have write my solution to redirect NSLog output to iOS app document folder (still get logs in the Xcode 6.3 console).

now i want to write the same log into a file in Mac in real time when i'm debugging the app.

Could you tell me how can i do it ?

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger/wiki/Integrating-NSLogger-in-your-application

Comment: thanks it's really cool tool but it's a client-server solution. my app is doing allot of HTTP/sip requests and one of my tests is to turn on airplane so the info will not be in real time.